# How to save/name result from loop in SageMath

Tags: python, loops, save, sage

I have the following code

```
N = 3
Z = matrix(24, 3); Z
for i in range(N - 1):
    for j in range(N - 1):
        for k in range(N - 1):
            m = matrix([[0, i, j], [i, 0, k], [j, k, 0]]); m
```

Result is:

```
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 1 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 0 0]
[1 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[0 0 1]
[1 1 0]
[0 1 0]
[1 0 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 1 0]
[1 0 1]
[0 1 0]
[0 1 1]
[1 0 0]
[1 0 0]
[0 1 1]
[1 0 1]
[1 1 0]
```

How can I save/name please the result of each iteration? In MATLAB we simply create a zero matrix and fill it at each iteration. Here it doesn't work. Or in other words how do I re-call every 3 lines from the result so I can use it in a future function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function

```
def m(i, j, k):
    return matrix([[0,i,j],[i,0,k],[j,k,0]])
```

and then just call it

```
sage: m(1,0,1)
[0 1 0]
[1 0 1]
[0 1 0]
```